# React.creatFactory equivalent with ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import App from './app.jsx';
...
let props = {};
res.render('layout', {
    reactHtml: React.renderToString(<App />)
});
```

How can I pass `props` into that `<App />` expression without defining it's props like `<App n={props.n} />` ?
Is there any equivalent for `React.createFactory()` and then do `React.renderToString(App(props))` in ES6?

Comment: What's wrong with using `React.createFactory` like before? Please show us your `app` code and how you've modified it with ES6.

Comment: No, nothing is wrong with using `createFactory`, my `app` using `class App extends React.Component`. I just want to know there is any other way to pass the whole `props` into `<App />` syntax. It no then I can still pass `App` to `createFactory()`, no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSX allows you to spread an object into an element, which is equivalent to passing every property as a prop:

```
<App {...props} />
```